# Do you have to create a new object when accessing inner nested classes?

Tags: java, class, oop, new-operator, inner-classes

Suppose you have class car in Java.
This class car has inner classes: speed, mileage, parts, identifications each with their own respective variables etc... some maybe with their own inner classes.

**Java code (example, not real java):**

```
public class car {
    public class speed {
          String inmiles;
          public class metric {
                String inkm;
          }
    }
    public car(arguments...){
         speed.inmiles = argument1;
         speed.metric.inkm = argument2;
    }
}
```

If you declare a car object with the `new` keyword in the main class (method), and want to provide the constructor with arguments to fill the inner classes' variablese, do you have to declare the inner classes in main as well?

Accessing the inner classes from within the car class does not work sadly, regardless whether the inner classes and variables are set to public.

Comment: "Accessing the inner classes from within the car class does not work sadly, regardless whether the inner classes and variables are set to public." What do you mean by that? And please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If it is not static - then yes, you need instance of outer class ;)

Comment: I updated the pseudocode to understandable java code. Even if I set all the inner classes to static I can't access the inner variable from within the constructor

Comment: `speed.inmiles` - you didn't create any _instance_ of class `speed` so you can't set any instance variables here. Note that your class should be called `Speed` as per the conventions and that should already raise a flag: `Speed.inmiles` would show you're accessing a class and not an instance (which might be referenced via a variable named `speed`). So add `Speed speed` to `Car` (rename that as well) and in your `Car()` constructor then create an instance of `Speed` - then you should be able to set `speed.inmiles` etc. (The same is true for `speed.metric.inkm` just one level deeper, i.e. )

Comment: And what is the error you're getting? You need to create an instance of the inner class to assign to it.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you I can now access the variables from within the constructor. This question can now be marked as solved.

Comment: I'll add an answer which you can then accept to mark the question as solved :)

Comment: And just saying: dont use any concept because you CAN use it. You use them because it is meaningful to apply a specific concept. In other words: just because you CAN use inner classes doesnt mean you should be using them for stuff like this. The concept "speed" is really independent of anything else. So why should Speed be an inner class of car? Sure, a car might have a field `private Speed currentSpeed` or something. But your idea of nesting inner classes to 3 levels is just: a bad take. Dont do that.

Comment: In the real world, inner classes are pretty rare in Java. They are the exceptional design element, not the default. And I cant recall to ever have seen 3-level class-in-class designs in the real world, like ever.

Comment: @GhostCat this is not true at all. Sure you can create a new class outside of your class for everything there is but that is simply in my honest opinion bad design. A car has a speedometer, seats etc... those things in my opinion should not be designed outside of the car class as they are integrated parts inside of a car. Otherwise you end up with dozens of components, specific to only one device cluttering your classes/file explorer when in reality, they should be put inside of the corresponding class. 
Speed was just an example. 
...............
Thomas absolutely, waiting for your answer.

Comment: To be precise: both approaches, yours and mine, are opinion, not fact. My opinion comes out of 25+ years of programming in Java, and 20+ years of professional software development with Java. If you are familiar with the "Clean code" work by Robert Martin, you should for example remember that we always prefer **complex networks of simple things** over *simple network of complex things*. You are correct, a car has a Speedometer, but the **concept** of Speed is NOT something that belongs INTO cars.

Comment: Your approach quickly leads into a nightmare. What if you want to model other vehicles that are not cars. Bicycles, ships, planes? Do they all get their "own" inner speed class. But how do you then "compare" objects of car.currentSpeed vs plane.currentSpeed? Okay, then you introduce a base class Vehicle. Cool. But ... a human can also walk with a certain speed. So now class Human gets to extend class Vehicle?

Comment: That is the thing: good OOP is about finding helpful abstractions, that have meaningful boundaries, and that are by default: **not stuffed together**. **Architecture** is **always** about the identifying the appropriate level of **decomposition**.

Comment: Sure: a car HAS a speedometer. A car HAS seats. But NOTHING in OOP says that the *definition* of the underlying classes Speed or Seat needs to be located inside the definition of car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, please note that class names should start with an uppercase letter to make it easier to distinguish between class and variable access. So `Car`, `Speed` and `Metric` should be used and thus `Speed.inmiles` would indicate `inmate` is meant to be a class variable and if it isn't you'd see the error more easily.

That being said, your code needs to create instances and then assign values to their fields/instance variables.

Very simplified example based on your code:

```
public class Car {
  Speed speed;

  public class Speed {
      String inmiles;
      Metric metric;

      public class Metric {
            String inkm;
      }
  }

  public Car(String speedInMiles, String speedInKm){
     //create the instance of Speed first
     speed = new Speed();
     speed.inmiles = speedInMiles;

     //create the instance of Metric
     //since Metric is an inner class of Speed you need an instance of Speed first
     //so we'll use the "speed" instance created earlier here
     speed.metric = speed.new Metric();
     speed.metric.inkm = speedInKm;
  }
}
```

Finally one design advice (there are more but I'll restrict myself :) ): don't use `String` for basically numeric values but use e.g. `double inMiles` etc. Also note that `inKm` could be calculated from `inMiles` so I'd not pass that separately.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat like in below example you can work with inner classes:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args){
         Test t = new Test(1, 2);
         System.out.println(t.a);
         t.printTest2B();
     }
}

class Test {
    public int a;
    public Test2 t2;
    class Test2 {
        int b;
        Test2(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public Test(int a, int b) {
        this.t2 = new Test2(b);
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void printTest2B() {
        System.out.println(t2.b);
    }
}
```